# Do Itsuki or Miku (or the other quints?) ask their dad why their tutor Fuutarou is a student in their own school and year level?

Tags: the-quintessential-quintuplets

In the pilot episode/series premiere, Itsuki and Miku think out loud complaining that their tutor is a student in their own school and year level, instead of a graduate of a bachelor's/associate's degree or even just a high school diploma.

Itsuki

> Itsuki: Why you? You're in my class. Is there not even one proper tutor in this town?
>
> [image]

Miku

> Miku: Why you? You're in our grade. Is there not even one...
>
> [image]

This is an extremely reasonable complaint and, apparently, in the manga, there's an explanation for it:

> The quints' dad and Fuutaro's dad know each other prior. And some other stuff.

Questions:

1. Do they ever ask their dad about it? Like call and say like

> 'Hey dad, you didn't mention our tutor is a student in our own school and year level, instead of a graduate of a bachelor's/associate's degree or even just a high school diploma. What's up with that?'

2. And actually why doesn't their dad just inform them in advance? Like

> 'Found a tutor for you guys. Tutor is in your own school and year level, Fuutaro Uesugi. I'm choosing someone from your own school and year level instead of someone with a bachelor's degree or even a high school diploma because [insert reasons].'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For 1

2 things

Thing 1A - My guess based on S02E02-S02E05 (The 7 goodbyes + the episode afterwards)

> They didn't even tell their dad about that Nino and Itsuki left the apartment.

Probably they just don't really talk to their dad that much.

Thing 1B - Actually they don't really care about studying that much. These aren't students who are really trying to improve their grades and just can't seem to be able to without external help. It probably sucks someone just in their grade and school is their kateikyoushi, but they just couldn't be bothered.

---

For 2

Actually their dad *did* tell them in advance that a kateikyoushi was coming. We know because Itsuki was expecting a kateikyoushi to come. You might wonder why their dad didn't tell the quints about the details, but I think the better question is why the quints didn't ask their dad in the 1st place about the tutor's qualifications. Then it's the same as above: They don't talk to their dad much, and they don't really care about studying.