# Why does the quintuplets' father hate Fuutarou?

Tags: the-quintessential-quintuplets

In the 5th episode of the 2nd season of The Quintessential Quintuplets, the quintuplets' father says he hates Futarou. [image]

Why does he hate Fuutarou? He seems to have met Fuutarou before and know about Fuutarou's dad, so I wonder whether the reason has something to do with Fuutarou's family. Does he have a bad relationship with Fuutarou's dad?

Answer (score -2):

1. In S02E04, it's revealed that Fuutarou shouted in their phone conversation in S02E03.

> [image]

2. At the end of S02E03 (7 goodbyes arc), the quints move out just so they can have Fuutarou as their kateikyoushi. This may be seen as some romantic interest. This is what the quints' dad has to say:

> I won't give my daughters to a man like you.
>
> [image]

I guess just your usual male protagonist vs dad of romantic interest conflict?

3. As for Fuutarou's dad and the quints' dad, see these

A - [Do Itsuki or Miku (or the other quints?) ask their dad why their tutor Fuutarou is a student in their own school and year level?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/66528/do-itsuki-or-miku-or-the-other-quints-ask-their-dad-why-their-tutor-fuutarou)

B - From [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/5ToubunNoHanayome/comments/t3ljon/looking_for_a_tutor_for_my_daughters_who/) which sorta spoils the manga (which I haven't read)

> The Uesugi dad and the quints' stepdad are old friends

but the above is I guess already hinted at anyway in S01E08 at the start when Fuutarou points out that their dad was the one who got Fuutarou the job (and even S01E01 when Raiha tells Fuutarou that their dad got them the job I guess).

Comment: Please stop linking to your own reddit post without proper disclosure. If you want to quote a certain section, please quote that relevant portion and not just have a link to some post where there is a comment without a proper citation. Explain how things are relevant rather than say it is a certain why because some rando on the internet said so.

Comment: @кяαzєя ok I actually remember that from another site now. thanks. I'll edit accordingly.